# Crash on loading large number of images

Tags: iphone

I am creating an app in which I am loading 800 jpg images for the Imageview.On occurance of different enevts different set of images are to be loaded for animation.on fire of first event it works fine but on 2nd event it crashes on iPhone.Any help?
my part of code is as below

```
for (int aniCount = 1; aniCount < 480; aniCount++){
UIImage *frameImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ani_soft_whimper_%i", aniCount] ofType: @"jpg"]];
[_arr_ImagesSoftWhimper addObject:frameImage];
}
imageView.animationImages = _arr_ImagesSoftWhimper;
```

and i m getting crash for these set of images.

Comment: put some code how to load the images...

Comment: use lazy loading using UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are running out of memory. But this is just a guess. Please provide some code.

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: Sorry, but I have not enough reputation points to comment on the original question.

Comment: hello @mkalmes  my part of code is as below for (int aniCount = 1; aniCount < 480; aniCount++) 
        {UIImage *frameImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ani_soft_whimper_%i", aniCount] ofType: @"jpg"]];
[_arr_ImagesSoftWhimper addObject:frameImage];} and i m getting crash for these set of images.

Comment: Is the code compiled with ARC?

Where did it crash exactly?

What's the wording of the crash report?

Answer (score 0):

1.if you are downloading from any server please call Asynchronous call.
2. check your image dimension,size,if dimension is big according to uiimageview frame then first resize or crop your image and then set into uiimageview.